# How do I fix factor() function returning na for column in R

Tags: r

I'm creating a training data set based on a customer's wage being <=50K or >50K. However, I've come across an issue with the factor() function in R where it is replacing all my wage values as NA.

```
newURL1 <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data"
customer <- read.table(newURL1,sep=",",header=FALSE,na.strings="?")
names(customer) <- c("ID","workclass","fnlwgt","education","education-num", "marital-Status","occupation","relationship","race","sex","capital-gain","capital-loss","hours-per-week","native-country","wage")
dfCustomer <- customer[-1] #get rid of id column
dfCustomer$wage <- factor(dfCustomer$wage,levels=c(2,4),labels=c("<=50K",">50K"))
```

after running this code, if you were to run `head(dfCustomer)`, you can see that the resulting wage column (the last column) is completely replaced with NA as shown below:

```
          workclass fnlwgt  education education-num      marital-Status         occupation   relationship   race     sex capital-gain capital-loss hours-per-week native-country wage
1         State-gov  77516  Bachelors            13       Never-married       Adm-clerical  Not-in-family  White    Male         2174            0             40  United-States <NA>
2  Self-emp-not-inc  83311  Bachelors            13  Married-civ-spouse    Exec-managerial        Husband  White    Male            0            0             13  United-States <NA>
3           Private 215646    HS-grad             9            Divorced  Handlers-cleaners  Not-in-family  White    Male            0            0             40  United-States <NA>
4           Private 234721       11th             7  Married-civ-spouse  Handlers-cleaners        Husband  Black    Male            0            0             40  United-States <NA>
5           Private 338409  Bachelors            13  Married-civ-spouse     Prof-specialty           Wife  Black  Female            0            0             40           Cuba <NA>
6           Private 284582    Masters            14  Married-civ-spouse    Exec-managerial           Wife  White  Female            0            0             40  United-States <NA>
```

After running it is supposed to show "<=50K" and ">50K" as values under wage

Comment: When you call `factor()`, why are you supplying `levels=`? If you leave that off you should be OK.

Comment: `levels(dfCustomer$wage)` yields `[1] " <=50K" " >50K"` (note the leading spaces). When you assign `"<=50K"` (..., no spaces), since this matches none of the data, it's replaced with `NA`.